# Zend Layout Question

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi i have a lot of common html that i want to use in a layout by doing :

zf enable layout

however the problem is want this layout to be shown on every action apart from the loginAction() that i have created within the controller?

Comment: Tip: Check the other similar questions on SO, this was already answered many times in many ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF I understand correct, you are looking for somthing like this:

```
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('foobaz');
```

Just add it to your loginAction and replace foobaz with the layout you really want to display.

More information about the layout can be found at:

```
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the layout in an action by using:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it the way @Stegeman said, by putting `$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('foobar');` on the init() of my login/authentication controller, where there are other pages like retrieve password page. So those pages all have a different layout than the default.